# Flattening out nested sublists into a data.frame

Tags: r

I often receive data in the form of nested lists. I end up writing various bits of code to flatten these out into `data.frames`. I'd like a more general solution so I'm not writing one off code for each separate list. So here's some example data to highlight my problem.

```
data_list <- list(structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T13:30:00", 
    value = -9999, data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, 
        qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T14:00:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T14:30:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T15:00:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T15:30:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T16:00:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T16:30:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T17:00:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T17:30:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality"
)), structure(list(local_date_time = "2010-01-05T18:00:00", value = -9999, 
    data_quality = list(structure(list(qualifierid = 19, qualifier_description = "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8", 
        valid = FALSE), .Names = c("qualifierid", "qualifier_description", 
    "valid")))), .Names = c("local_date_time", "value", "data_quality")))
```

The simplest way of course is to `rbind` the list. `data.table`'s `rbindlist` is fast on larger lists like so:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(data_list)
```

but this returns:

```
        local_date_time value data_quality
 1: 2010-01-05T13:30:00 -9999       <list>
 2: 2010-01-05T14:00:00 -9999       <list>
 3: 2010-01-05T14:30:00 -9999       <list>
 4: 2010-01-05T15:00:00 -9999       <list>
 5: 2010-01-05T15:30:00 -9999       <list>
 6: 2010-01-05T16:00:00 -9999       <list>
 7: 2010-01-05T16:30:00 -9999       <list>
 8: 2010-01-05T17:00:00 -9999       <list>
 9: 2010-01-05T17:30:00 -9999       <list>
10: 2010-01-05T18:00:00 -9999       <list>
```

which isn't ideal because the last column is actually a nested list of 3 items. I could do this with `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
result <- ldply(data_list, function(x) {
    cbind(data.frame(t(unlist(x[1:2]))), data.frame(t(unlist(x[3]))))
})
```

This works fine. Is there a way to generalize this approach to lists that might have different formats of nested lists? If the list is a single level, a simple `do.call(rbind, list_name)` should do it. In this case I know the 3rd element has a sublist. But often I don't know. Writing a custom wrapper for each would be somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a function once called `LinearizeNestedList` by an [Akhil S Bhel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533691/asb) (who is sometimes on SO). It "flattens" nested lists.

In your case, you would want to "flatten" the sublists, not the main list itself.

Perhaps it can be of use in your situation as follows:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477")
# Sourcing https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477/raw/1bd86c697b89de9941834882f1085c8312076e38/LinearizeNestedList.R
# SHA-1 hash of file is dde479195258dbad9367274ceedbd5a68251478a
x <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(data_list, LinearizeNestedList))
x
#        local_date_time value data_quality.1.qualifierid
# 2  2010-01-05T13:30:00 -9999                         19
# 21 2010-01-05T14:00:00 -9999                         19
# 3  2010-01-05T14:30:00 -9999                         19
# 4  2010-01-05T15:00:00 -9999                         19
# 5  2010-01-05T15:30:00 -9999                         19
# 6  2010-01-05T16:00:00 -9999                         19
# 7  2010-01-05T16:30:00 -9999                         19
# 8  2010-01-05T17:00:00 -9999                         19
# 9  2010-01-05T17:30:00 -9999                         19
# 10 2010-01-05T18:00:00 -9999                         19
#             data_quality.1.qualifier_description data_quality.1.valid
# 2  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 21 Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 3  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 4  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 5  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 6  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 7  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 8  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 9  Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
# 10 Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8                FALSE
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Now the challenge will be to figure out a license to include this in my package, especially since the code above has none and is not on CRAN.

Comment: @Maiasaura, as I mentioned, I've seen Akhil on Stack Overflow, so perhaps you can ping him on one of his recent questions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `lapply` with `as.data.frame`  will also do, at least as long as you have just one level of nesting:

```
> res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(data_list, as.data.frame))
> str(res)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ local_date_time                   : Factor w/ 10 levels "2010-01-05T13:30:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ value                             : num  -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 ...
 $ data_quality.qualifierid          : num  19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19
 $ data_quality.qualifier_description: Factor w/ 1 level "Passed sanity check; see incident report IR_8": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ data_quality.valid                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```